# Creating Terrain of Golf Course in Unity? (use Unity Terrain or 3d software)

Tags: unity, terrain

Hi all I wanted to create some simple, but pretty, golf courses for a Unity game.

I've not found much success with the built-in terrain maker as the painting of textures is not sharp edges).

Is it best to have only the basic layout in the terrain and then have separate meshes for the fairways and greens (and if so, how would I go about making that 'wrap' exactly onto the terrains surface to lie flat on it?)

Perhaps I can paint the textures somehow with much more definition on the edges but I can't find how to do it. If this is the case, how is it best to identify to the other gameobjects such as the ball as to what kind of surface it is on?

Comment: I don't think that Unity terrain system is very well-equipped to do what you want it to do. You will likely have to implement a lot of stuff yourself.

Comment: ok  i was  thinking this may be the case.  Guess its gonna be a long process learning 3d modelling to get the fairways to stick like a decal to the rest of the terrain (and the green etc). I'll keep tinkering. thanks